# Fire onclick event in Firefox

Tags: firefox, onclick

I have an HTML table which is built dynamically. To the table I have an event handler attached, which sorts a column when the column is clicked. I wish to force a column sort (i.e. sort the table by a specific column) once the page has finished loading.

Currently, I use `document.getElementById(ElementName).click();`
This works in IE but not Firefox. How can I achieve the same effect in Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling the click handler, just invoke the handler function directly.  Assuming that your handler is on a span containing the column name,  it might look something like:

```
<span id='defaultColumn' onclick='sortBy(this);'>Column</span>
```

So you would do:

```
sortBy( document.getElementById('defaultColumn') );
```

Or maybe

```
<span id='defaultColumn' onclick='sortBy("Column Name");'>Column Name</span>
```

which would give you

```
sortBy( document.getElementById('defaultColumn').innerHTML );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'dispatchEvent', detail in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dispatchEvent

```
document.getElementById(ElementName).dispatchEvent(eventObj)
```